# Is "I left the bed" an appropriate expression to mean "I got up"?

Tags: sentence

I searched online and it says that "I left the bed" means "I recoverd from illness." I wonder whether I can use this expression to mean that I got up.

Comment: It's not a common way to express the concept, but is valid English and would generally be understood.  (Though it might cause some confusion as to whether you "got out" of the bed or left the vicinity of the bed.)  (I would never be inclined to interpret it as "recovered from an illness" unless the context strongly hinted at this.)

Comment: The far more common way to say it would be "I got out of bed."

Comment: But I can imagine a doctor saying, “You are not allowed to leave your bed for the next three days.”

Comment: "I left my bed" would sound more natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for diversity in your language, and therefore resulting to the phrase "I left the bed" instead of "I got out of bed", than you might have to consider some other options. There's nothing wrong with "I left the bed", but it is also a phrase meaning "I recovered from illness", as you said. So, unless the situation tells us the character leaving bed is not ill (in an indirect way preferably)|, then there's no problem. No one will think the person is ill. But if you feel someone might think this person has just recovered from illness, consider these other examples.

> I fell out of bed

Might signify it was a rough morning and that the character isn't that motivated to wake up. You could also say; "I rolled out of bed".

> I arose from the bed

Sounds a bit weird, and doesn't necessarily imply he/she got out of bed.

> I departed from the bed

Could work, especially if it's spoken by a sociopath wording himself in a cold and formal manner.

But then again, this answer was made by me assuming you were writing a book. You said "use", so it may mean you're talking about day-to-day speech. If so, then there's no problem about saying "I left the bed" because most people will know you haven't been sick lately. If someone asks that you can simply tell them you aren't.